# What does this log message from a collator node mean?

Tags: substrate-node, collator, log

What does this log message from a collator node mean? Is it bad, should it be fixed or ignored?

```
Error: Service(Client(Backend("Invalid argument: Column families not opened: col12, col11, col10, col9, col8, col7, col6, col5, col4, col3, col2, col1, col0")))
```

Comment: Not sure why it appears, but can this help you? https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/issues/349